# Declaring an Array - Angular 4

Tags: angular, typescript

I am trying to push some dynamic data into an array.

```
export class Test implements OnInit {
 private lineChart: Array<any>;
 }
```

Further in the code, I generate dynamically some data and do a lineChart.push(data) into the empty lineChart array, it is working but the data are not well formatted to be used. Any ideas on how to end up with the result below ?

Here is the expected result :

```
private lineChart: Array<any> = [
    { data: [65, 59, 80, 81, 56, 55, 40], label: 'toto' },
    { data: [28, 48, 40, 19, 86, 27, 90], label: 'tata' },
    { data: [81, 56, 55, 48, 40, 19, 34], label: 'titi' },
  ]
```

---

I am trying to use this Javascript librabry : https://alligator.io/angular/chartjs-ng2-charts/

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({ ... })
export class AppComponent {
  chartOptions = {
    responsive: true
  };

  chartData = [
    { data: [330, 600, 260, 700], label: 'Account A' },
    { data: [120, 455, 100, 340], label: 'Account B' },
    { data: [45, 67, 800, 500], label: 'Account C' }
  ];

  chartLabels = ['January', 'February', 'Mars', 'April'];

  onChartClick(event) {
    console.log(event);
  }
}
```

chartData is the array I want to get at the end using the data generated dynamically.

Comment: what do you mean by `data are not well formatted`? what's the error?

Comment: Please provide a [mcve] of your issue.

Comment: Basically, when I try differently and declare the array : private lineChartData: Array<any> = [{data: [], label: ''}]; I got as the result the first row, which is a good start. Maybe the declaration of the LineChart array is not matching the expected data ?

Comment: did you try using something like ```interface LineChart{
  data:number[],
  label:string
}``` and ```lineChart: LineChart[] = []``` ?

Answer (score 0):

It should be

```
private lineChart: Array<{
        data: number[],
        label: string,
    }> = [
        { data: [65, 59, 80, 81, 56, 55, 40], label: 'toto' },
        { data: [28, 48, 40, 19, 86, 27, 90], label: 'tata' },
        { data: [81, 56, 55, 48, 40, 19, 34], label: 'titi' },
    ];
```

Comment: In that case ```private lineChart: Array<{
        data: number[],
        label: string,
    }>``` whould be enough for the definition

Comment: This declaration is still not working properly. The only one that works at the moment is : private lineChart: Array<any> = [{data: [], label: ''}]; (But it only push the first element at index 0 of the dynamic data).